# How to check if the user used his first name and last name in the name field again ? Validation Rule (Laravel7)

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Hello guys I have a simple Question about Laravel Validation System I was thinking what if the user entered his Firstname and Lastname twice in the Name field ???

How can I prevent this with validation message and thank you for help ...

This is my **RegisterController**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: it's just an option for the users

Answer (score 1):

You have the `different` rule to achieve that

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users', 'different:lastname'],
        'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users','different:firstname'],
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    ]);
}
```